# How do I solve this TemplateSyntaxError in Django that says "Could not parse the remainder"

Tags: python, django

I am trying to render a block of HTML code repeatedly using for loop. But Django throws a TemplateSyntaxError when I reload my browser

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
    {% for number in range(3) %}
    <!--Slide {{ number + 1 }}-->
    <div class="row">
        {% for number in range(6) %}
        <!--Slide 1 Col {{ number + 1 }}-->
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I expected a repeated rendering of the blocks inside the for loop but got "TemplateSyntaxError at /
Could not parse the remainder: '(3)' from 'range(3)'" instead

Comment: You can not make function calls (with parameters in templates), so `range(3)` will not work. Pass it through the context to the template, or use Jina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django does not allow to make function calls (with parameters) as well as subscripting in the templates. The rationale is that business logic should not be part of the template. You thus can pass the `range(3)` and `range(6)` object through the context to the template. The `{{ number + 1 }}` will not work either, since such operators are not supported either.

An alternative is using [*Jinja*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/), which is a template engine that *does* allow to use such Python syntax in the templates.

Since the numbers are quite small, a third options is to use string literals instead:

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
    {% for row in '123' %}
    <!--Slide {{ row }}-->
    <div class="row">
        {% for col in '123456' %}
        <!--Slide 1 Col {{ col }}-->
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```